# How to sort this dictionary by key

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, dictionary

I want to sort this Dictionary by keys when I click on the button. This is what it should look like: https://gyazo.com/2f03244e94627153e8f7cb3fef4862d5

Tried to do it somehow with bubble sort but couldnt figure it out.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //Dictionary<int, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        dict.Clear();

        //int asd = Convert.ToInt32(txt1.Text);
        string asd = Convert.ToString(txt2.Text);

        dict.Add(Convert.ToInt32(txt1.Text), asd);

        string lol = "";

        foreach (var pair in dict)
        {
            lol += pair.Key + "-" + pair.Value;
        }

        list.Items.Add(lol);
    }

    private void btn_sort_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int asd = dict.ElementAt(1).Key;

         for (int i = 1; i < dict.Count; i++)
         {
             for (int j = i + 1; j < dict.Count; j++)
             {
                 if (dict.ElementAt(i).Key > dict.ElementAt(j).Key)
                 {


                     asd = dict.ElementAt(i).Key;

                     dict.ElementAt(i).Key = dict.ElementAt(j).Key;

                     dict.ElementAt(j).Key = asd;
                 }
             }
         }
   }
```

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: Did you try a SortedDictionary?

Comment: You can sort it by using  dict.OrderBy((kvp) => kvp.Key);

Comment: @jdweng not sure how to do it. Tried something like this but doesnt work https://gyazo.com/0ae0f663ef23f99125ff76c91d16269b

Comment: It must work.  It wound like it is sorting but not in the order you are expecting.  What values are not sorting?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/b43a97d12d1af830e6237b8a09d57bb6

Comment: It is sorting by the first ascii character and not as a number.  You need to extract the digits and parse to a number to get the sort to work.

Comment: You are clearing the dictionary every time you add a new item. Why?  dict.Clear();

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the [SortedList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netframework-4.7.2) class instead of a dictionary. The dictionary is a hash table and has a different usage to what you intend to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print out the contents of an unordered dictionary in order by key then sort the dictionary using `OrderBy`

```
public void PrintSortedDictionary(Dictionary<int, string> dictionary)
{
    dictionary.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key).ToList().ForEach(kvp => Console.WriteLine($"Key: {kvp.Key} - Value: {kvp.Value}"));
}
```

Comment: its a wpf so i dont just wanna print it out with consolewriteline

Comment: The sorting of the dictionary doesn't change, it's just order by the key. Once the dictionary is sorted you can do what you whatever you like, put the contents in a label, string or wherever you need them.